# Datanode not starting on Slave Nodes for Apache Hadoop+Spark Setup

Tags: apache-hadoop

I know similar questions have been asked and I already looked through a lot of them to figure out what the issue might be, but to no avail.

I am a College student currently working on a Big Data Project. I have to setup 5 Computers (1 Master + 4 slaves) to run Apache Spark on YARN.
I had an initial Hadoop setup that I setup Spark on but I messed on some steps as the guides were from different sources.

So, I decided to start fresh with a guide for both Hadoop and Spark from the same source.
I found and followed this [Hadoop Setup Guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/hadoop/how-to-install-and-set-up-hadoop-cluster/).

Note: Since the PCs have a good amount of Memory, I did not [Configure Memory Allocation](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/hadoop/how-to-install-and-set-up-hadoop-cluster/#configure-memory-allocation) and left it as is.

After setting Hadoop up, I tried to start the daemons with `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`.

On the master Node, `jps` showed this:

```
21922 Jps
21603 NameNode
21655 DataNode
21787 SecondaryNameNode
```

but, on all the slave nodes `jps` came up with nothing:

```
19819 Jps
```

Is there something that I could have messed up here or is there an error in the Guide?

I had setup Hadoop previously and use [this guide](http://kishorer747.blogspot.com/2014/10/setting-up-hadoop-241-multi-node.html).

I tried some solutions that I found online but was unable to fix the issue. 
For reference, the [Spark Installation Guide](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/hadoop/install-configure-run-spark-on-top-of-hadoop-yarn-cluster/) though I haven't started with this yet.

I would really appreciate any and all help.
Thanks!